# angularjs: can't get out loop to check for existing object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

```
if (currentFirstNumber != null && currentSecondNumber != null) {
    var card = {
        id: rank + "_" + suit,
        rank: rank,
        suit: suit.toString()
    };
}
var exists = false;
for (i = 0; i < $scope.communityCards.length; i++) {
    if (card.id == $scope.communityCards[i].id) {
        exists = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!exists) {
    $scope.communityCards.push(card);
}
```

I'm trying to get a card object in an array of cards, but first I would like to check if it already exists because the cards are generated from a hash.

If the card doesn't exists, everyting goes well. But when it already exists I get stuck, it always returns to check if it exists. While it should exit the for loop and continue with the parent loop that goes trough the hash to generate a new card (not visible here).

Comment: Can you provide any more context and / or specify the problem?

Comment: I have a loop going through a sha512 hash and every 2 chars I generate a poker card from them (f.e. 5 of hearts). When that card is generated and put into a **card** object, I'd like to check if that card was generated before, before putting it into an array of generated cards.

Answer (score 0):

```
 card_ids = $scope.communityCards[i].map(function(card){ return card.id; });
 matched_cards = card_ids.filter(function(id){ return id==card.id; });

 //check matched_cards.length
 //if it is >0 then card is exit else not exist

 if(matched_cards.length>0){ 
   $scope.communityCards.push(card);
 }


 //---------------example--------------
  a = [{t:1}, {t:2}, {t:3}]
  c = a.map(function(e){ return e.t; })
  d = c.filter(function(e){ return e==2; });
  d.length
```

Comment: I can't do this because I only have 1 card at that moment? Or I am looking at it the wrong way?